# Normalizing audio signal

Tags: python, audio, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

I want to reliably convert both recorded audio (through microphone) and processed audio (WAV file) to the same discretized representations in Python using [specgram](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram).

My process is as follows:

1. get raw samples (read from file or stream from mic)
2. perform some normalization (???)
3. perform FFT with windowing to generate spectrogram (plotting freq vs. time with amplitude peaks)
4. discretize peaks in audio then memorize

Basically, by the time I get to the last discretization process I want to as reliably as possible come to the same value in freq/time/amplitude space for same song.

My problem is how do I account for volume (ie, the amplitudes of the samples) being different in recorded and WAV-read audio?

My options for normalization (maybe?):

- Divide all samples in window by mean before FFT
- [Detrend](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.detrend) all samples in window before FFT
- Divide all samples in window by max amplitude sample value (sensitive to noise and outliers) before FFT
- Divide all amplitudes in spectrogram by mean

How should I tackle this problem? I have almost no signal processing knowledge or experience.

Comment: since the noise will probably never have the highest amplitudes, you can 1) divide each sample by its respective maximum amplitue before the FFT; 2) then multiply by the target common amplitude also before FFT; 3) perform the FFT in the normalized sample

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but if all you care about is the peak locations in the spectrogram, there is no need to normalize amplitude.

Comment: @SaulloCastro: what is a "target common amplitude"?

Comment: @BjornRoche: my understanding is that the spectrogram represents the amplitude of the signal (which is tied to the volume) as a function of time of the window and frequency. if that thinking is correct, wouldn't it make sense to normalize amplitude to account for different scalar multiples of volume?

Comment: @lollercoaster By target common amplitude I meant the common amplitude that you want to have at the end, the common volume...

Comment: @SaulloCastro: that I "want to have"...? volume common to what? maybe I wasn't too clear about my goal. I want to memorize song from disk and then when listening to audio through mic be able to process to attain same amplitude peaks

Comment: Are you trying to implement an algorithm like shazam?

Comment: @BjornRoche: yes, precisely

Comment: Have you read the shazam paper? Off the top of my head, I don't think they normalize, just locate. http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf

Comment: yes. figured they might not have mentioned it. see here for my problem: http://imgur.com/a/GLkch#0. first image is a recorded wav file - noise dominates. second image is a song with reasonable peaks. song2 is a normal song but for some reason too many peaks - in all my recognition tasks songs like these dominate. however normalizations so far have only made this domination worse (more pure red)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spectra of the WAV file and the recorded audio are never going to have exactly the same shape because the audio data from the microphone source undergoes additional disturbances on it's way to your computer. These disturbances could be equalized out, but that's probably more work than you want to do.

As far as normalization goes, I'd recommend scaling the microphone signal's spectrum so that its energy matches that of the WAV file's spectrum (where "energy" is the sum of the squared magnitude of FFT coefficients).

Now, you mentioned that you want the signals' spectrograms to be as similar as possible. Since a spectrogram is a plot of a signal's spectrum over time, you might want to experiment with renormalizing at each time interval vs. just normalizing once over the entire audio recording.

Comment: to your 3rd point, yes I normalize over each window interval, not the whole recording. 

to your 2nd point: by scale you mean divide the spectrum periodogram by the sum of the square of the abs value of the coeffs? this would have to be done after the FFT though, which I'm suspicious of as good advice...

Comment: and I agree the spectra won't be identical, but as long as salient peaks are the same, that's fine

Comment: @lollercoaster Let my try to clarify my second point...

Suppose you have two audio signals, a and b. If you take the FFT of these signals you'll get their spectra, A and B. 

Now let's say that you want to scale A so that it's the same "size" as B. Since I'm going to use signal energy as a measure of "size" I want to find a constant coefficient such that sum(abs(c*A)**2) = sum(abs(B)**2), where c is the constant coefficient.

Comment: ok sure, my question is whether signal energy equates to volume and why I don't normalize before FFT

Comment: Yes, signal energy equates to volume. As far as doing the normalization before doing the FFT, yes, you totally can. In fact, the operations are equivalent. You can calculate the sum of square absolute values of the audio samples or you can calculate the sum of square absolute values of the FFT coefficients. According to Parseval's Theorem they're equivalent.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem